# How to differ between a upper or lower case words in a SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, select

Basically i feel like the problem is simple. but cant find any fix for it.

In a login form, i use php to query my database which on its side check the passed username and password by selecting from the database table any row that has that 2 values.

What seems to be the problem is when i login for ex.

> user: mm
>
> pass: oo

that works. and that is right as they are on the db table.

but now if i use

> user: MM
>
> pass: oo

still works?? which should not. As my db has only user as 'mm' not 'MM'.
I need it to distinguish between upper and lower
because in other rows i have mix of upper an lower letters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to change the collation/encoding of the column from a "case-insensitive" encoding to a case-sensitive one, such as `utf8_general_cs` or `latin1_general_cs`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use case sensitive encoding

> From [**10.1.2. Character Sets and Collations in MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-mysql.html)
>
> There is a convention for collation names: They start with the name of the character set with which they are associated, they usually include a language name, and they end with _ci (case insensitive), _cs (case sensitive), or _bin (binary).

so use case sensitive like `utf8_general_cs` or `latin1_general_cs`

Comment: thanks all the answers where right. :) but had to accept the first reply

Comment: @MoAdel  no problem its perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

You can update the table using the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table`  CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;
```

Where it says `latin1_general_cs`, the `cs` specifies that it is case sensitive. If you ever desire it not to be case sensitive in the future you can just use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table`  CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

the `ci` spcifies that it is case insensitive.

Comment: thanksfor pointing the ci and cs part.. all the answers i got where right.but had to accept the first reply